Spring JPA with pagination and QueryDSL: order data in DB by enum names rather that enum values order
On the web-page, I have a table that shows transactions. It uses pagination in spring backend app. So, the ordering of data is perfomed by backend side, and because of pagination - BE orders data in database. One of the table columns is "Error reason" that show an error message. But when I try to sort this column, it doesn't order in alpabetic order as expected.
I have a Entity that includes a enum field 'reason'.
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class TransactionError extends BaseEntity {

    ... fields ...
    private TransactionErrorReason reason;
    ... fields ...
}

The enum looks like that:
@Getter
public enum TransactionErrorReason {

    ABOVE_MAX_WEIGHT("AboveMaxWeight", "aboveMaxWeight"),
    BELOW_MIN_WEIGHT("BelowMinWeight", "belowMinWeight"),
    DUPLICATE("Duplicate", "duplicate"),
    DIFFERENCE_IN_NUMBER_OF_ARTICLES("DifferenceInNumberOfArticles", "differenceInNumberOfArticles"),
    UNKNOWN_ARTICLE("UnknownArticle", "unknownArticle"),
    NULL_MATERIAL_TYPE("NullMaterialType", "nullMaterialType"),
    STOREID_DOESNT_MATCH_MACHINE_SERIAL("StoreIdDoesntMatchMachineSerial", "storeIdDoesntMatch"),
    
    ... other enum values that are placed NOT in alphabetic order ...

    private final String reason;
    private final String directoryName;

    TransactionErrorReason(String reason, String directoryName) {
        this.reason = reason;
        this.directoryName = directoryName;
    }
}

in DB, it store 'reason' as int that represents ordial value of enum. So, it's not impossible to order it in alpabetic order directly. To retrieve data from DB, I use this repository that uses JPA.
I need to order enum field in DB by enum name (or 'reason' property) rather than ordial (that is stored in DB)

I think you mean ordinal (and not ordial).
